# postgresql create data file path from application using userchangelog.xml file a

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase-sql

How to create data file path if not exists in postgres server using userchangelog.xml file changeset id

i tried following ways but getting many errors. can any one suggest how can we create data file path from the application if it doesn't exist at the location while creating database using changesets

```
   DO $$ DECLARE
   BEGIN
   PERFORM pg_catalog.pg_stat_file('${DATAFILEPATHNAME}', false);
   EXCEPTION WHEN undefined_file THEN        
        EXECUTE format('mkdir -p %s', '${DATAFILEPATHNAME}');
     
   END;
   $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: `many errors`, care to share?

Comment: By the way, `mkdir` is not a valid SQL statement, that will never work.

Comment: `plpgsql` is a trusted language. Per [Language install](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xplang-install.html): *Since PL functions are executed inside the database server, the TRUSTED flag should only be given for languages that do not allow access to database server internals or the file system. The languages PL/pgSQL, PL/Tcl, and PL/Perl are considered trusted; the languages PL/TclU, PL/PerlU, and PL/PythonU are designed to provide unlimited functionality and should not be marked trusted.*